# Vue: change component prop from parent component on click, radio buttons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have two components: `Toggle.vue` which is basically a button and a `TestToggle.vue` which has two `Toggle` components inside. I want to be able for the toggle elements to serve as a radio button of sorts: only one can be selected at a time.

It is supposed to look like this (only one button is active at a time):

[image]

However I can select two buttons:

[image]

which isn't right.

**Toggle.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div class="rounded-full m-5 w-40 
                flex justify-center 
                p-2 cursor-pointer"
         :class = "status ? 'bg-green-700 
                             hover:bg-green-600' :
                            'bg-red-700 
                             hover:bg-red-600'"
         v-on:click="status = true">
        <p>{{text}} : {{status}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:  {
            text:  {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            status: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**TestToggle.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Active: {{activeTab}}</p>
        <Toggle v-on:click = "activeTab = 1"
                text="Toggle 1 "/>
        <Toggle v-on:click = "activeTab = 2"
                text = "Toggle 2"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
     import Toggle from '../test/Toggle.vue';

    export default {
        components: {Toggle},

         data: function () {
             return {
                activeTab: 1
            }
        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

I think I need to set `status = false` from `TestToggle` to `Toggle` when another `Toggle` is clicked? How do I do that? Or should I do it completely differently?

Another problem is that I can't update `activeTab` data property inside `TestToggle` component: it always shows `1`...

**EDIT**:

I tried this code (as suggested in the answer), but it just doesn't work: the buttons don't react to clicks:

**Toggle.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div class="rounded-full m-5 w-40
                flex justify-center
                p-2 cursor-pointer"
         :class = "status ? 'bg-green-700 hover:bg-green-600' :
                            'bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-600'">
    <p>{{text}} : {{status}}</p>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        props:  {
            text:  {
                type: String,
                default: ''
            },
            status: {
                type: Boolean,
                default: false
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**TestToggle.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Active: {{activeTab}}</p>
        <Toggle v-on:click = "activeTab = 1"
                text="Toggle 1 "
                v-bind:status="activeTab === 1"/>
        <Toggle v-on:click = "activeTab = 2"
                text = "Toggle 2"
                v-bind:status="activeTab === 2"/>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
     import Toggle from '.././toggle-so/Toggle.vue';

    export default {
        components: {Toggle},

        data: function () {
            return {
                activeTab: 1
            }
        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You declare `status` as a prop in Toggle.vue but don't pass anything down from TestToggle.vue

Comment: Try setting `status` as a data property in TestToggle.vue and then pass it to Toggle.vue. Also, you should bind your classes instead of using a ternary: `:class="{ 'bg-green-700': status, 'bg-red-700': !status }"`

Comment: But `status` belongs to `Toggle` component. And it's exactly the `pass it to Toggle.vue` part that I'm not sure about

Comment: Okay, well declare `status` as a data property in Toggle.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Toggle.vue`, `status` is declared as a prop, so you should not modify it:

```html
<template>
    <div class="rounded-full m-5 w-40 
                flex justify-center 
                p-2 cursor-pointer"
         :class = "status ? 'bg-green-700 
                             hover:bg-green-600' :
                            'bg-red-700 
                             hover:bg-red-600'"
        <p>{{text}} : {{status}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

but pass it to `Toggle.vue` from `TestToggle.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <p>Active: {{activeTab}}</p>
        <Toggle v-on:click.native = "activeTab = 1"
                text="Toggle 1 "
                v-bind:status="activeTab === 1"/>
        <Toggle v-on:click.native = "activeTab = 2"
                text = "Toggle 2"
                v-bind:status="activeTab === 2"/>
    </div>
</template>
```

If you change the `status` in `Toggle.vue`, you make it independent of every other Toggle, but if you want a radio button behavior, each status is dependent of other statuses. That's why you need to manage if from the parent component.

You also need to use the `native` [event modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components) to listen to the `div` click of the children.

I made a simple JSFiddle to show a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ncrhLba2/1/).

Comment: Why shouldn't I modify it just because it's a prop? I'd think putting the `click -> reverse status` logic inside the `Toggle.vue` would adhere to the DRY principles?

Comment: Props are meant to be passed from parent to children, therefore it's not recommended to modify it in children because it can be overriden by the parent

Comment: When I run your code and click on the buttons, nothing changes - neither the text nor the colors (see question edit)

Comment: Answer updated. You also need to use the `native` event modifier to be able to listen to `div` clicks from the child component.

Comment: Thank you a lot!